# The light passes through edges of a model

Tags: modeling, light

The problem is as in the pictures. When Rendered mode is on, light passes through the edges of the model. When exporting to Unity3D, the problem is the same.

[image]

[image]

Blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ghvqRvovUO_ul_0DJACBYCKao5_dKI9g/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Select your light, and in the light properties panel, tick the "contact shadows" box.

[image]

Comment: I did it but nothing has changed.

Comment: Hmm. Not  sure then. Maybe try giving your plane some thickness? It's kind of hard to tell anything else from the photo.

Comment: Could you please see what is wrong with this model?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ghvqRvovUO_ul_0DJACBYCKao5_dKI9g/view?usp=sharing

Comment: First off, your light type is sun, of which 1000 is WAY too high a value. 10-15 is considered (almost too) strong for a sun light, and most people don't go over 5. I suggest changing it's type to a point light and setting the brightness to 2000 or something... or move it closer. However, If you want a light with good shadows coming (seemingly uniformly) from one direction, I would use a large area light instead of a sun. Looks more natural I think.

Comment: Also, you should up the distance of your contact shadows to something like 2M, and in your render properties tab, under shadows, make sure both "high bitdepth" and "soft shadows" are checked. It's not PERFECT, but it makes it a whole lot better.